# Pthread timeout

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads

All I waint to do is launch a thread and see if it has finished in a certain period of time.

OS: linux; language: C++.

I'd like not to use non portable functions (like suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1244687/777833)).

Is there any way to do that, other than using a mutex and a 
condition variable (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5750851/777833))? There is no shared data between the two threads, so technically I would not need a mutex.
All I want is, for the function that launches the thread, to continue if

- thread has finished or
- a certain time elapsed.

... and keep the code as simple as I can.

Comment: I highly recommend the boost thread libraries, or there are some concurrency goodies in C++11, if you have a compiler that supports them. How precise a timing do you need for this? Profiling might be the way to go.

Comment: What's wrong with a condition variable, a bool flag and a mutex?

Comment: sam: thanks, I'll read more into that.

@Torsten: I want to keep it as simple as possible and it seemed to be too much for a simple fact like that. Just thought I should ask. However, as a last resort I'll come to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use boost::thread, the "usual" bool flag, condition variable, mutex approach is as simple as:

```
bool ready = false;
boost::mutex              mutex;
boost::condition_variable cv;

// function to be executed by your thread
void foo() 
{
    // lengthy calculation
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock( mutex );
    ready = true;
    cv.notify_one();
}

// will return, if the thread stopped
bool wait_for_foo( time_point abs_time )
{
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock( mutex );

    while ( !ready && cv.wait_until( lock, abs_time ) != cv_status::no_timeout )
      ;

    return ready;
}
```

Ok, isn't much simpler then using posix ;-)

Comment: Yep, a combination of Nicolai's solution with a condition variable, in order to avoid the polling and the spinning. I'll use it with posix, though, as the code will later be ported to linux arm. (a mutex, a condition variable and a bool only to wait for a thread to finish... but it seems to be the best way)

Comment: `wait_until` doesn't return bool, and takes a `time_point` not a duration. I think you mean `while (!ready && cv.wait_until(lock, abstime) != cv_status::timeout)`

Comment: ain't it dangerous to make ready a 'simple' bool type? IMO you should add 'volatile' before or compiler might do value optymizations and under release code you might get different behavior, right?

Comment: @zodi volatile has usually nothing to do with threading. If you have a compiler / library pair that enables you to write multithreading software, you get the guaranty that this pair works like documented.

Comment: oh but it does much with threading - info from msdn: "The volatile keyword is a type qualifier used to declare that an object can be modified in the program by something such as the operating system, the hardware, or a concurrently executing thread. (...) Microsoft specific - Objects declared as volatile are not used in certain optimizations because their values can change at any time. The system always reads the current value of a volatile object at the point it is requested, even if a previous instruction asked for a value from the same object."

Comment: "Microsoft Specific" ;-) http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2007/11/30/volatile-almost-useless-for-multi-threaded-programming/

Comment: well, good article, yet almost 5 years old... anyway I still think volatile is good in some cases, not every operation requires use of synchronization objects (mutexes, critical sections etc.)

Answer (score 1):

you can create timer thread and once timer is reached to a `timeout` cancel that thraed. No need to have mutex.code is like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define TIMEOUT 1*60 //in secend
int count = 0;
pthread_t t_main;   //Thread id for main thread
void * timer_thread()
{
    while (TIMEOUT > count)
    {
        sleep(1);  //sleep for a secand
        count++;
    }
    printf("killinn main thread\n");
    pthread_cancel(t_main); // cancel main thread

}
void * m_thread()
{
    pthread_t t_timer; //Thread id for timer thread
    if (-1 == pthread_create(&t_timer, NULL, timer_thread, NULL))
    {
        perror("pthread_create");
        return NULL;
    }
    //DO your work...
    while(1)
    {
        sleep(2);
    }
}

int main()
{
        if ( -1 == pthread_create(&t_main, NULL, m_thread, NULL))
    {
        perror("pthread_create");
        return -1;
    }
    if (-1 == pthread_join(t_main, NULL))
    {
        perror("pthread_join");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need a condition variable, you could just have the other thread lock a mutex on entry and unlock it when it's finished, and have the launching thread use [`pthread_mutex_timedlock`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_timedlock.html) (optional in older versions of POSIX, required in POSIX 2008) to try to acquire the mutex, timing out if the other thread hasn't finished.

Comment: How do you make sure, that the started thread acquire the mutex before the waiting thread?

Comment: The only problem is that if the other thread does not get to lock the mutex before the first one checks for it, it will not wait at all... So I tried locking it before launching the thread, but afterwards it would try to lock it again (the timedlock), which is not ok, as it is already locked by the same thread... I hope I wrote that clear enough...

Comment: Add a simple boolean initialized to `false`, and have the second thread flip it to `true` on startup (when already holding the mutex). Then the main thread would loop around `pthread_mutex_timedlock`, releasing the mutex and retrying if that boolean is still `false`.

Comment: This might be very ineffective because you have to poll and second, a mutex is usually designed with a fast path in mind. On a multi processor machine there might be some spinning before the waiting thread is put to block.

Comment: Who cares, this is initialization. Your example with CVs requires threads to enter kernel and wait. Mine spins. Which one is more effective? I don't know since we don't have any criteria for "effectiveness" here.

Comment: We have the criteria of "effectiveness" everywhere :).

Comment: But the wait thread can already do useful things instead of pooling the start thread. On single threaded machine this might even lead to the wait thread spinning all it's time slice before the started thread gets the cpu. If the wait thread starts to join the work thread after the work thread stopped, there will be just two uncontended lock/unlocks. If the wait thread have to wait for the work thread, there will be an addition wait on device that is designed for waiting.

Comment: Yup, have to admit you are right about UP machines. Keep forgetting those things exist :)

Comment: I was assuming the launching thread would have something useful to do before it starts waiting for the other thread. If not, who cares about a fast path anyway, you've got an entire thread sitting there doing nothing but wait anyway, spinning until you know the other thread has started isn't going to take long