# Something regarding a previous 'condition variable' post

Tags: linux, operating-system, linux-kernel

The question is about a post regarding conditional variable that i glanced over. [condition variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716437/condition-variable)

The author first give a bugged example:

```
/* in thread 1 */
pthread_mutex_lock(mx); 
if (state == GOOD) {
    pthread_mutex_unlock(mx);  // Here !
    wait_for_event();
    pthread_mutex_lock(mx);
}
pthread_mutex_unlock(mx);


/* in thread 2 */
pthread_mutex_lock(mx);
state = GOOD;
pthread_mutex_unlock(mx);
signal_event(); /* expecting to wake thread 1 up */
```

and explains as follows:

'This pseudocode sample carries a bug. What happens if scheduler decides to switch context from thread 1 to thread 2 after pthread_mutex_unlock(mx), but before wait_for_event(). In this case, thread 2 will not wake thread 1 and thread 1 will continue sleeping, possibly forever.'

I know how conditional variable should be used, as author demonstrated in same post later.

I can see that in this bugged example, the 'state == GOOD' judgement and 'wait_for_event()' is NOT locked as a whole by a mutex. And if thread 1 is context switched right after the first '**pthread_mutex_unlock(mx);**', thread 2 can change 'state' to something else (BAD?), and signal to wake up thread 1 to proceed in the 'state == GOOD' logic, which i think is wrong.

But why author says 'In this case, thread 2 will not wake thread 1 and thread 1 will continue sleeping, possibly forever.'?

Isn't 'signal_event();' still called in thread 2? Was my understanding correct at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug is caused by the semantics of `signal_event()` and `wait_for_event()`.  If `signal_event()` is called when no one is stuck in `wait_for_event()`, the signal is lost.

Besides a context switch, the same problem occurs if thread 2 runs fast and thread 1 is slow.  In that case, the time in thread 1 between

```
pthread_mutex_unlock(mx);
```

and

```
wait_for_event();
```

could be when thread2 does all its operations, sending a signal into oblivion (because no one is waiting for it).  Then thread 1 waits, and it will never get the signal (unless thread 2 runs again for some reason).

Comment: Thanks wallyk. Good to know. What are the real linux function names for this wait_for_event()/signal_event() semantics situation? I am new to this and currently only looked at a signal handler chapter of a book.