# Alternative to an infinite loop

Tags: c#, timer, schedule, long-running-processes

I have an infinite loop:-

```
while(true)
{
//display an image
}
```

Obviously the CPU goes up.

I have used:

```
Thread.Sleep(100);
Thread.Sleep(0);
ApplicationDoEvents() - I know i shouldn't
```

This loop will never end unless the application is ended.  Are they any other alternatives to an infinite loop?

I am displaying the image in a usercontrol and I am overriding the `OnPaint` event...

```
if (CurrentFrame != null)
{
    g.DrawImageUnscaled(CurrentFrame, 0,0);
}



public void NewFrame(Image _currentFrame)
{
    if (CurrentFrame != null)
    {
        CurrentFrame.Dispose();
    }
    CurrentFrame = _currentFrame;
    Invalidate();
    //Update();  
}
```

Any insights/suggestions/recommendations would be most welcome...

Comment: What windowing toolkit are you using? Drawing should usually be invoked by the windowing toolkit(which in turn is invoked by the windowing system)

Comment: Hi, just to confirm my comment to Jonathan. I am currently overriding the onpaint event within a usercontrol and I am drawing the bitmap object via the graphics object that is made available via the onpaint object. I should have explained that a bit better but I was focused on the infinite loop

Comment: My focus is on the infinite loop and the different strategies i can employ instead of it. I am using c#. I should have stated that in my original question. Obviously, what i am 'kicking' off via my infinite loop has a bearing on the CPU usage but i would get the CPU issue whether I 'kicked' off any code or not.

Comment: You were quite right to pull me up on how I was rendering my graphics and under what context. My fault really I should have detailed better what i was currently doing.  Really appreciate your time though.

Comment: Can you elaborate why you need that loop at all please?

Comment: @user846281: an infinite loop is unlikely to be the correct solution to your problem.  If you're painting something there's a hook exposed for you to add your own behaviour; if you're repeating something endlessly there are timer mechanisms that you can use to re-call your method on a regular basis.  If you can explain in more detail what you're trying to do then you'll get a more suitable answer.

Comment: Hi, i am using vlc to connect to a rtsp stream.  I get 10 frames per second. I display it.  The cpu on my pc is about 12%.  when i use a lower spec it goes to 80%.  Thus i am looking for an alternative to the infinite loop.  I have used the montior.wait and monitor.pause. This works well on my PC but performs even worse on the lower spec PC.  This rtsp is a continuous feed that is local to my home network.  I have to receive the feed in JPGS...

Comment: Don't loop at all. Draw the bitmap in the Paint event handler.

Comment: hi Raymond, that was what i am attempting to do now. I am using a static bitmap and i am updating that bitmap via the bitmap data and then the onpaint event will take of the rest. I realised a few hours ago to do that :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal thing to do when you need a thread to sleep until some condition is true is to use a [condition variable](https://www.google.com/search?q=condition+variable). The thread locks a mutex and then passes it to a condition variable and blocks (and the lock on the mutex is then temporarily released). Then, when the condition that it's waiting for is true, the thread that made that condition true signals the condition variable, and that thread wakes up, reacquiring the lock on the mutex, and continues on its merry way. The thing to watch out for though is that condition variables can have spurious wake-ups (and sometimes multiple threads can be waiting on the same condition), so there needs to be a flag of some sort to indicate when the condition is true, and when the thread wakes up from the condition variable, it checks that flag and blocks on the condition variable again if the flag isn't true. The mutex that is being used with the condition variable is also used to protect that flag.

The D runtime has a condition variable in [`core.sync.condition`](http://dlang.org/phobos/core_sync_condition.html).

There are also other good questions relating to condition variables on stack overflow such as this one: [condition variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716437/condition-variable)

Now, as for your particular use case, I have to concur with the comment by Idan Arye that it seems a bit off that you would be trying to do this with painting with a windowing toolkit. Normally, the way that that works is that you override the `OnPaint` function (or whatever that particular toolkit calls it) and then the windowing toolkit calls the function for you. You don't tell it to paint yourself or have to worry about waiting for a condition or anything like that. So, it sounds like you may be misunderstanding how to use the windowing toolkit that you're using.

Comment: Hi Jonathan and Idan, thank you both for your responses.  I will address the 'Windowing Toolkit' whilst I look into the condition variable explanation. I am overriding the paint within a usercontrol. The NewFrame 'updates/changes' the current bitmap and the onpaint event (via the graphics object) and draws in the image. Is that not the correct way to do things?  I probably did not explain this properly or have really got this wrong?

Comment: HI Jonathan, I am using C# but i have found the equivilent of this sync condition. I did look at it before but was unsure how to apply it or whether it was what i needed.  Your answer has helped me to focus on using this now - thanks.

Comment: The CPU usage is not bad (12%) but on a friends older laptop it is around 80%.  obviously the available RAM and clock speed has a bearing. If I have to specify a certain basic PC spec then that is what I have to do. I was just making sure i was coding efficently. I did had a volatile conditional variable that was being checked in my loop which did help a bit.  I also swapped from a while(true) loop to a Do while(true) loop as i was told this was a better way to do it (something to do with the order of the condition within the loop assisted the compiler in ignoring this as an infinite loop).

Comment: Jury is still out on that one.  As I said i will now look at this monitior.pulse/monitior.wait consumer/producer strategy.  Please feel free to tell me if i am still not making sense :)

Comment: sorry for commenting in snippets i could seem to upload all i wanted in 1 one go. Also, grammar is not my thing...

Comment: Hi, I have put this in and it works well.  I see the logic of it all and it was very easy to implement and I feel a bit stupid now.  thank you very much..

Comment: I think i spoke to soon. Whilst it did improve performance on the higher spec PC it actually reduced performance on my lower spec laptop. I have to assume that the on/off of the thread is causing an overhead  :(

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of things you can do here. The first is to do updates at a standard rate, using a timer. If you're using Windows Forms, you can drop a Timer component on your form and set the period to, say 15 ms. That'll give you (approximately) 66 frame updates per second.

Note that the .NET timers will give you, at best, about 15 ms resolution. You could roll your own implementation of one of the Windows timers to give you 1 ms resolution, but doing so will greatly complicate your code.

The other thing you can do is have the code that updates the `CurrentFrame` image call the update method, and have that update method not update more often than some set rate. You do this by starting a `Stopwatch` at the beginning of your program, and checking the time elapsed since the last update. Something like:

```
private Stopwatch FrameTimer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
private long LastUpdateTime = 0;
private const long MinUpdateMs = 10; // minimum time between updates

void DoUpdate()
{
    long currentTime = FrameTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    if ((currentTime - LastUpdateTime) < MinUpdateMs)
    {
        // updated within the last 10 ms
        return;
    }
    LastUpdateTime = currentTime;
    if (CurrentFrame != null)
    {
        g.DrawImageUnscaled(CurrentFrame, 0,0);
    }
}
```

The second option is very effective, although you run the risk of not getting the last update if there isn't continual change. If there can be a long period between updates to your `CurrentFrame`, then you can have a timer that forces an update every second or so. If you do that, you want to add some synchronization in the `DoUpdate` method to prevent concurrent updates. I would suggest:

```
private object UpdateLock = new object();
void DoUpdate()
{
    if (!Monitor.TryEnter(UpdateLock))
    {
        // update already in progress
        return;
    }
    try
    {
        long currentTime = FrameTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        if ((currentTime - LastUpdateTime) < MinUpdateMs)
        {
            // updated within the last 10 ms
            return;
        }
        LastUpdateTime = currentTime;
        if (CurrentFrame != null)
        {
            g.DrawImageUnscaled(CurrentFrame, 0,0);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Monitor.Exit(UpdateLock);
    }
}
```